# C# Entity Framework many to many data seeding

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to seed a default "admin" user and associate roles using entity framework. I'm able to seed the User and Roles, but having issues with the UserRoles many to many relationship.

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The seed entity for entity type 'UserRole' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'Role' set. To seed relationships,  add the entity seed to 'UserRole' and specify the foreign key values {'RoleId'}

UserRole Model:

```
public class UserRole
    {
        [Key]
        [MaxLength(36)]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(36)")]
        public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(60)]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; } = "Hive_API";

        [Required]
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(60)]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; } = "Hive_API";

        public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(36)]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(36)")]
        public string UserId { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Required]
        public User User { get; set; } = null;

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(36)]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(36)")]
        public string RoleId { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Required]
        public Role Role { get; set; } = null; 
    }
```

Seeding Data:

```
       public HiveSeedData(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            User adminUser = new User
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                FirstName = "Default",
                LastName = "Administrator",
                EmailAddress = "admin@admin.com",
                Password = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword("admin")
            };

            Role adminRole = new Role
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                RoleName = "ADMINISTRATOR"
            };

            Role taskRole = new Role
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                RoleName = "USER"
            };

            UserRole adminToAdminRole = new UserRole
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                UserId = adminUser.Id,
                User = adminUser,
                RoleId = adminRole.Id,
                Role = adminRole
            };


            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasData(
                    adminUser
            );
            modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
                .ToTable("Roles");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
                .HasData(
                   adminRole, taskRole
                );
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
                .ToTable("UserRoles")
                .HasData(
                    adminToAdminRole
                );
        }
```

Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Comment: It says don't set the navigation properties. Just set the foreign keys and seed the db. (Talking about `UserRole` entity.)

Comment: Please read the answer to the post marked as duplicate, and the documentation link inside. But shortly, use pre generated Guids for PKs, and don't assign navigation properties of the related entities (many-to-many, one-to-many, one-to-one, doesn't matter), just FKs.